# Can ICU4J return multiple alternative transliterations?

Tags: translation, icu4j

For example I want to hand ICU4J a string containing أسامة, which is the name "Osama" as written in Arabic, and I want it to give me back a list of possible transliterations to Latin, for example

```
["Osama", "Ushamma", "Asama"]
```

Is this possible with ICU4J or any other transliteration product?